# Button won't open webview layout on button press

Tags: android, eclipse, android-webview, android-button

I have a button setup on my main layout which upon pressing the button, it should open up a webview layout.

But nothing happens when the button is pressed.

Below is my code.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.homediyassistant.screen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.AddRecord" />
        <activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.UpdateRecord" />
        <activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.DeleteRecord" />
        <activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.ViewRecord" />
        <activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.AddUpdateValues" >
            <activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.WebViewActivity" >
   </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Home DIY Assistant"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Add New Room"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="View Rooms"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="DIY Website"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

webview.xml

```
    </LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

webviewactivity.java

```
package com.homediyassistant.screen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }


}
```

webviewbutton.java

```
package com.homediyassistant.screen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class WebViewButton extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_webview);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: is the `WebView` in `main.xml` or `webview.xml`?

Comment: webview is not in main.xml

Comment: have you added `WebViewActivity` in `manifest`?

Comment: I reviewed your code. It seems alright. The code must call webView. ARe u clicking on **DIY Website** button, because only that button you have given a listener.

Comment: When I press the button in question, this is the read out I get....  05-06 13:50:36.548: D/GestureDetector(27528): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0

Comment: Yes DIY Website is the button in question.

Comment: I have added the activity to the manifest but I get errors. I have edited the original post to show my manifest.

Comment: there is no activity with name `WebViewButton` in the manifest?

Comment: [2013-05-06 14:07:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Documents and Settings\sstoilkovic\workspace\Home DIY Assistant\AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "activity" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</activity>".
[2013-05-06 14:07:24 - Home DIY Assistant] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Answer (score 1):

you hadn't closed the activity tag 
use

```
<activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.AddUpdateValues"/>
```

instead of

```
<activity android:name="com.homediyassistant.screen.AddUpdateValues" >
```